# Unsolicited recommendations for alternate libraries. Not an answer?

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer

I sometimes see comments and answers of the format:

> Why are you using [that library]? Use [this other library] instead.

Obviously, there are times where this is totally appropriate, like:

> Unfortunately, this isn't supported in [that library]. If you use [this other library] instead, however, you can achieve the same outcome. Here's a code sample.

Or, [as I've sometimes answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20168073/3025856):

> [That library] is out of date, and no longer maintained. If you're starting a new project, I'd recommend migrating to [this other library], which supports many of the same features—including the functionality you're asking about.

Or, more borderline cases like:

> I'm not sure how to solve this in [that library], but here's a solution in [this other library] which you could use instead, assuming you're not attached to [that library].

Other times, though it reads primarily as a personal preference. When I see these, I usually respond with a downvote (if it's an answer) and a comment to the effect of:

> The OP was specifically asking about [that library]. Is there a reason they need to migrate to [this other library] to solve their problem? Or is that just a personal preference? If the former, can you update your answer to explain why?

Is this the appropriate response? Or should I *also* be flagging these as *Not an Answer* (NAA)? Based on the [NAA FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer) I wouldn't assume so. But I see these often enough that I wanted to verify.

(Obviously, I'm not talking about explicit self-promotion, which should instead be flagged as *Spam*.)

Unfortunately, I haven't been keeping references to these answers, though I was reminded of this today on [a case that I'd consider borderline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61223238/how-to-find-cosine-distance-using-math-module-in-python/61223501#61223501) (and, thus, didn't bother downvoting or commenting on). In absence of that, I hope these fictitious examples are sufficiently illustrative.

Comment: That might depend on the exact question, but I'm not sure. If the question is "How to achieve X with Y?" and the answer is "Don't use Y, use Z", then it might be an attempt to answer the question as XY problem. In any case vital explanation would be missing in such an answer making it not very useful.

Comment: If it's a comment it's completely fine.

Comment: @kemicofaghost: I definitely wouldn’t consider reporting a comment. Though I might [challenge the guidance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/239590/dictionary-or-custom-collection#comment471165_239590) if it’s not relevant to the question. (Acknowledging that example is on Code Review and, thus, prescriptive and opinionated feedback is often expected.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those ***are*** answers. They may not be good answers, but they *are*, so don't flag them as **"NAA"**. That flag will only be declined.

What you *can* do, is to downvote the answer.
Also, if the answer is *"Use library <X>"*, It's very likely that the question is off-topic, and should probably be closed.

Comment: Thank you for the clarity. I’m definitely not talking about cases where the OP _solicited_ recommendations for libraries, but rather where a respondent doesn’t _like_ the library the OP is using and thus recommends a different one. Regardless, whenever I see a recommendation (in e.g. a review queue) the first thing I do is check the question to conform whether it should be closed as _Opinion-based_.

Comment: I’m thinking more along the lines of an OP asking how to solve a problem using Angular, and the respondent saying “You shouldn’t use Angular. Use Vue instead.” In other words, a completely unsolicited opinion-based response to an otherwise legitimate question.

Comment: @JeremyCaney that still is an answer to a question. Not flagable as NAA.

Comment: "NAA" is only for answers that don't actually _attempt_ to answer the question. Gibberish, _"Thanks"_, _"I have this problem too!"_, stuff like that.

Comment: @rene: Perfect. This is exactly the type of clarity I was hoping for here. I’ll be sure not to report these as _Not an Answer_, but will continue to downvote and/or comment as appropriate. Thank you again.

Comment: @JeremyCaney Flagging NAA is kind of a game of [Jeopardy!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeopardy!). If you can come up with a non-trick question  where that answer would fit, NAA is not the right flag.

Comment: @rene: I love that way of phrasing it. That also  fits nicely with something mentioned in SOCVR the other day (which I was visiting based on your recommendation): If an answer could be a valid solution to _any_ question on the site, then it’s not NAA. That’s been an incredibly useful heuristic to adopt. (Admittedly, I hadn’t thought about applying it in this case, but that’s a failure of imagination on my part—and further evidence that I’d be lousy on “Jeopardy!”.)